# Remove/edit the heatmap legend from pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend, heatmap

I am trying to either set the heatmap legend to be the same size as the main plot, or failing that, remove it entirely.

What I currently have:

[image]

The picture also includes SOME of the things I've tried to remove, move or edit it. But I have also tried other things.

here, world is simply the import from geopandas:

[image]

And I have added some percentile data to some of the countries.

Nothing fancy going on, but can't figure out why the legend isn't editable in any way.

Comment: the official documentation: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mapping.html#creating-a-legend